# Difference between RegisterCodeBlockAction and RegisterOperationBlockAction

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm currently learning Roslyn's DiagnosticAnalyzer API and I would like to ask what's the fundamental difference between

## 1) [AnalysisContext.RegisterCodeBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.analysiscontext.registercodeblockaction?view=roslyn-dotnet)

> Register an action to be executed after semantic analysis of a method body or an expression appearing outside a method body. A code block action reports Diagnostics about code blocks.

and

## 2) [AnalysisContext.RegisterOperationBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.analysiscontext.registeroperationblockaction?view=roslyn-dotnet)

> Register an action to be executed after semantic analysis of a method body or an expression appearing outside a method body. An operation block action reports Diagnostics about operation blocks.

so I can choose the right one for my use case in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RegisterCodeBlock` register `Action` that work over a some of [code block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.codeblockanalysiscontext.-ctor?view=roslyn-dotnet) that is represented as a `SyntaxNode`, that can be block syntax node,  statement node, expression node and so on.

However, `RegisterOperationBlock` register the similar `Action`, but over a some of [operation block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.operationblockanalysiscontext.-ctor?view=roslyn-dotnet) that is represented as [IOperation](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Operations/IOperation.cs,7743f66521e66763), that can be block of operation, statement operation, expression operation and so on.

`SyntaxNode` is corresponding representation of input text in the AST, so it dependent to the language, instead of `IOperation` represent a some common action (operation), for example simple assignment, method invocation, conversion, and as it represents the operation under common logic (semantic) it doesn't depend to the language.

Comment: It looks like operations API nicely abstracts a lot of language details. One thing I'm missing tho is access to semantic model which is given by SyntaxNode callbacks by default. When I want to examine type of awaiter, only way I found is
```var syntax = x.Operation.Syntax;
var semanticModel = x.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntax.SyntaxTree);
var awaiter = semanticModel.GetAwaitExpressionInfo((AwaitExpressionSyntax) syntax).GetAwaiterMethod.ReturnType;```
While it works, it doesn't feel right to me to allocate new semantic model each time. Did I miss something?

Comment: @WELLCZECH, more nicely abstraction (and often faster) than `IOperation` is `ISymbol`, because it's semantic info over a lot of things: local variable, parameter, field, property, method an so on. You did use `IMethodSymbol.ReturnType` in your example above) `GetAwaitExpressionInfo` is very well when your know that the syntax is `AwaitExpressionSyntax`, else you can try to `GetSymbolInfo` and determine what kind of symbol you did get. You can use cache of `SemanticModel` to avoid the redundant allocations